# Dismiss dialog of custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialog

I have a custom preference, TimePreference, which extends `DialogPreference`. It has a custom dialog resource, which looks like this

[image: Three buttons with their IDs]

The source is

```
@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View v){
    super.onBindDialogView(v);

    v.findViewById(R.id.butCancel).setOnClickListener(onClickL);
    v.findViewById(R.id.butNow).setOnClickListener(onClickL);
    v.findViewById(R.id.butOK).setOnClickListener(onClickL);
    //....
}
//...
private final View.OnClickListener onClickL = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(lTag, v + " clicked");
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.butOK: saveToSP(false);break;
            case R.id.butNow: saveToSP(true);
        }

        try {
            getDialog().dismiss(); //may throw null pointer
        } catch (Exception e) { Log.w(lTag, "Exc @onClickL", e); }
    }
};
//...
```

I found a bug where, if you clicked the same preference really fast *twice* (at the preference screen) two dialogs would open. You could close the first one but, when you would try to close the second, the app would crash. It was a NullPointerException, so I enclosed it in a try-catch block. Now, the exception is caught, but the buttons do not close the dialog. Notice that, by clicking  <kbd>back</kbd>, it **does** close.

How can I close the second dialog *(possibly by simulating the behaviour of the back button?)* ? Note, I want the API level below 10.

Comment: the reason of this dialog appearance is your custom or built-in?

Comment: Why don't you disable the button when clicked, and enable it back when the dialog closes?

Comment: @Saqib Built-in, I set it at the .xml file

Comment: @BadaroJr. I tried it, but when clicked at the second dialog, they get disabled and the dialog does not close (same exception as before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a soultion. I have a static boolean, which shows if there is an open dialog.

```
private static boolean isAnyDialogOpen = false;
```

<s>On dialog bind, I set it to true, 
And after I close the dialog, I set it to false.</s>
Turned out that even this was problematic, but the solution was easier

```
@Override
protected void onClick() {
    if (isAnyDialogOpen)
        Log.i(lTag, "there is a dialog already");
    else {
        isAnyDialogOpen = true;
        super.onClick();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Log.d(lTag, "dismiss, dialog= "+dialog);

    isAnyDialogOpen = false;
    if (dialog != null) super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```